# How to pass arguments to main function

Tags: flutter

In the famous [flutter_architecture_samples](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples) repo, and exactly in this [main.dart](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples/blob/master/bloc_flutter/lib/main.dart), the main function needs 2 arguments:

```
void main({
  @required TodosInteractor todosInteractor,
  @required UserRepository userRepository,
}) {
  runApp(Injector(
    todosInteractor: todosInteractor,
    userRepository: userRepository,
    child: TodosBlocProvider(
      bloc: TodosListBloc(todosInteractor),
      child: MaterialApp(...
```

This is the first time I see a flutter main function with arguments, can someone explain? And especially how are you supposed to pass arguments to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that, because when you start an app on your device there are also no parameters that are passed. 
you can check this [How do you pass arguments from command line to main in Flutter/Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004302/how-do-you-pass-arguments-from-command-line-to-main-in-flutter-dart)