# Flutter Getx - "Xxx" not found. You need to call "Get.put(Xxx())" - But I have called Get.put(Xxx())

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-get, flutter-getx

I have this global bindings class to initialise some services and I need it to be initialised straight away:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:vepo/data/data_provider/local_data_provider.dart';
import 'package:vepo/data/data_source/local_data_source.dart';

import 'services/authentication_service.dart';

class GlobalBindings extends Bindings {
  final LocalDataProvider _localDataProvider = LocalDataProvider();
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put<AuthenticationService>(AuthenticationService(), permanent: true);
    Get.put<LocalDataProvider>(_localDataProvider, permanent: true);
    Get.put<LocalDataSource>(LocalDataSource(_localDataProvider),
        permanent: true);
  }
}
```

Which is in my initialBindings:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Vepo',
      initialRoute: AppPages.INITIAL,
      initialBinding: GlobalBindings(),
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      defaultTransition: Transition.rightToLeft,
      getPages: AppPages.routes,
      home: Root(),
      theme: homeTheme,
    );
  }
}
```

Then in a class constructor I try to "find" it:

```
class UserLocalRepository extends VpService implements IUserLocalRepository {
  UserLocalRepository() {
    localDataSource = Get.find<LocalDataSource>();
  }

  LocalDataSource localDataSource;
```

And I get this error:

```
══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown building App(dirty):
"LocalDataSource" not found. You need to call "Get.put(LocalDataSource())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>LocalDataSource())"

The relevant error-causing widget was
App
lib/main.dart:17
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      GetInstance.find
package:get/…/src/get_instance.dart:272
#1      Inst.find
package:get/…/src/extension_instance.dart:66
#2      new UserLocalRepository
package:vepo/…/user/user_local_repository.dart:10
#3      new LoggedOutNickNameBinding
package:vepo/…/logged_out_nickname/logged_out_nick_name_binding.dart:11
#4      AppPages.routes
package:vepo/…/routes/app_pages.dart:29
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

This is the binding mentioned in the error message:

```
class LoggedOutNickNameBinding extends Bindings {
  LoggedOutNickNameBinding() {
    _repository = Get.put(UserLocalRepository());
  }

  IUserLocalRepository _repository;

  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<LoggedOutNickNameController>(
      () => LoggedOutNickNameController(_repository),
    );
  }
}
```

Why are the "initialBindings" not initialised, so that my app can "find" them when the app starts up?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm guessing that there's a timing / ordering mismatch with when your GlobalBindings.dependencies() method gets called and when you need those resources.

You could try initializing your Bindings class *prior* to GetMaterialApp instead of passing your Bindings class *to* GetMaterialApp.

```
void main() async {
  //WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // uncomment if needed for resource initialization
  GlobalBindings().dependencies();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

#### Tangent

Just guessing here, but are some of the classes you're initializing via Get.put are slow-startup (i.e. async) before they are ready to use?

If so you could use

```
Get.putAsync<YourClass>(() async {
 // init YourClass here
 return await YourClass.slowInit();

}
```

#### Example

I recently ran an exercise of performing async Bindings initialization prior to app being loaded for user interaction.  Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

enum Version {
  lazy,
  wait
}
// Cmd-line args/Env vars: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64686348/2301224
const String version = String.fromEnvironment('VERSION');
const Version running = version == "lazy" ? Version.lazy : Version.wait;

void main() async {
  //WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // if needed for resources
  if (running == Version.lazy) {
    print('running LAZY version');
    LazyBindings().dependencies();
  }

  if (running == Version.wait) {
    print('running AWAIT version');
    await AwaitBindings().dependencies(); // await is key here
  }

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class LazyBindings extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<MyDbController>(() => MyDbController());
  }
}

/// Simulates a slow (2 sec.) init of a data access object.
/// Calling [await] dependencies(), your app will wait until dependencies are loaded.
class AwaitBindings extends Bindings {
  @override
  Future<void> dependencies() async {
    await Get.putAsync<MyDbController>(() async {
      Dao _dao = await Dao.createAsync();
      return MyDbController(myDao: _dao);
    });
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyDbController dbc = Get.find();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('GetX Bindings'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Obx(() => Text(dbc.dbItem.value)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDbController extends GetxController {
  Dao myDao;

  MyDbController({this.myDao});

  RxString dbItem = 'Awaiting data'.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    initDao();
  }

  Future<void> initDao() async {
    // instantiate Dao only if null (i.e. not supplied in constructor)
    myDao ??= await Dao.createAsync();
    dbItem.value = myDao.dbValue;
  }
}

class Dao {
  String dbValue;

  Dao._privateConstructor();

  static Future<Dao> createAsync() async {
    var dao = Dao._privateConstructor();
    print('Dao.createAsync() called');
    return dao._initAsync();
  }

  /// Simulates a long-loading process such as remote DB connection or device
  /// file storage access.
  Future<Dao> _initAsync() async {
    dbValue = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 'Some DB data');
    print('Dao._initAsync done');
    return this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In *my* case:

```
TestCartController? cartController;

if(condition){
 cartController = Get.isRegistered<TestCartController>()
            ? Get.find<TestCartController>()
            : Get.put(TestCartController());

}
```

But in some other widget, I was referring to the above controller as:

```
final cartController = Get.find<TestCartController>();
```

The type mismatch issue is because both instances are different, so it was causing a problem for me. I simply removed that `?` mark and it worked.

```
TestCartController cartController;

if(condition){
 cartController = Get.isRegistered<TestCartController>()
            ? Get.find<TestCartController>()
            : Get.put(TestCartController());

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Add fenix : true;
```

---

```
class AppBinding implements Bindings {
      @override
      void dependencies() {
        Get.lazyPut<GeneralController>(() => GeneralController(), fenix: true);
        Get.lazyPut<UserController>(() => UserController(), fenix: true);
      }
    }
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what did you change? Why did you change it? *Why* does it work? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73697946/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: OK, that will not be anytime soon: *"This account is temporarily suspended for plagiarism."*

Answer (score 2):

**Reason**: It happened when Get.find() was called before Get.put(Controller). Calling Get.find() *before* initializing the Get.put() shows the error.

**Solution**: Simply you can call Get.put(controller) into your main class as below. So then Get.find() from any class will get it.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final YourController controller = Get.put(YourController());
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
    ......

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your controller class is not bind with any `stateful/stateless` class then you can initialise the controller class in the main method like this

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // init app controller
  AppController appController =
  await Get.putAsync<AppController>(() async => AppController(), permanent: true);
  // init temp storage
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error and was able to resolve it by replacing Obx with GetX. Instead of:

```
Obx(() => Text(controller.text)),
```

use

```
GetX<MyController>(builder:(c) => Text(c.text)),
```

Note that you should use the GetX builder controller (c) instead of the default one (controller).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your LocalDataSource extends and implement these classes.

```
LocalDataSource extends GetxController implements GetxService
```