# Cannot call Flutter Singleton from another package

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I am trying to import an asynchronous function in Flutter to handle securely storing user data. The problem is I keep getting the following error:

```
packages/authentication_repository/lib/src/authentication_repository.dart:64:15:
Error: Method not found: 'set'. await SecureStorageService.set(
                                      ^^^
```

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class SecureStorageService {
  static SecureStorageService _intance;
  FlutterSecureStorage flutterSecureStorage;

  SecureStorageService._internal() {
    this.flutterSecureStorage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  }

  static Future<SecureStorageService> getInstance() async {
    if (_intance == null) {
      _intance = SecureStorageService._internal();
    }
    return _intance;
  }

  Future<void> set(String key, String value) async {
    await this.flutterSecureStorage.write(key: key, value: value);
  }

  Future<String> get(String key) async {
    return await this.flutterSecureStorage.read(key: key);
  }

  Future<void> clear() async {
    await this.flutterSecureStorage.deleteAll();
  }
}
```

And then I import the code like follows:

```
import 'package:crowdplan_flutter/storage_util.dart';

...

class AuthenticationRepository {
  final _controller = StreamController<AuthenticationStatus>();
  final secureStorage = SecureStorageService.getInstance();

...

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
          'email': email,
          'password': password,
          'client_id': clientId,
        }),
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.body);
        print(json.decode(response.body)['access_token']);
        print(json.decode(response.body)['refresh_token']);
        await secureStorage.set(
            key: 'access_token',
            value: json.decode(response.body)['access_token']);
        await secureStorage.set(
            key: 'refresh_token',
            value: json.decode(response.body)['refresh_token']);
        await secureStorage.set(
            key: 'user_id', value: json.decode(response.body)['user_id']);
        _controller.add(AuthenticationStatus.authenticated);
      }
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print('Exception occurred: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace');
    }
  }
```

My Singleton is initiated in my main.dart file like so.

```
void main() async {
  await SecureStorageService.getInstance();
  runApp(App(
    authenticationRepository: AuthenticationRepository(),
    userRepository: UserRepository(),
  ));
}
```

I am new to Flutter so this might be a new noob error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` method isn't `static` and can't be accessed with `SecureStorageService.set`

```
  Future<void> set(String key, String value) async {
    await this.flutterSecureStorage.write(key: key, value: value);
  }
```

I see in the 2nd code snippet that you've assigned the singleton to `secureStorage`.

Did you mean to access it with something like?:

```
  secureStorage.set()
```

#### Part 2 - Code Example

Perhaps the `async getInstance()` in the singleton class is tripping you up.  It doesn't need to be async (nor should it be).  (In some cases you may want an async initializer instead of a constructor.  See the [bottom of the Example code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64841379/2301224) for a use-case.)

`SecureStorageService` (the singleton) gets instantiated in your `main()` method so inside `AuthenticationRepository` it'll use that same instance and be ready to use.

```
class AuthenticationRepository {
  final secureStorage = SecureStorageService.getInstance;
  // ↑ will get the same instance created in main()
```

The code sample in the question doesn't specify where/when the http.post method is being called, but I'm guessing it's an initialization / setup for `AuthenticationRepository` so I've mocked up an `initStorage()` method inside it.

This `initStorage()` call will use the `SecureStorageService` singleton, with a call to its `secureStorage.set()` method.

Hopefully this example helps you spot a difference between our code samples to figure out what's going wrong.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Mocking FlutterSecureStorage
/// Note that the actual package FlutterSecureStorage does not have an async
/// constructor nor initializer
class FlutterSecureStorage {
  Map<String,String> data = {};

  Future<void> write({String key, String value}) async {
    data[key] = value;
  }

  Future<String> read({String key}) async {
    print('FSS read - returning value: ${data[key]}');
    return data[key];
  }
}

class SecureStorageService {
  /// for singleton ↓ instance should be final and uses private constructor
  static final SecureStorageService _instance = SecureStorageService._internal();
  FlutterSecureStorage flutterSecureStorage;

  /// Private constructor, not async
  SecureStorageService._internal() {
    flutterSecureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  }

  /// This doesn't need to be async. FlutterSecureStorage (FSS) doesn't have an async initializer
  /// and constructors are generally never async
  /*static Future<SecureStorageService> getInstance() async {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = SecureStorageService._internal();
    }
    return _instance;
  }*/

  /// static singleton instance getter, not async
  static SecureStorageService get getInstance => _instance;

  /// don't need "this" keyword & could use FSS methods directly, but leaving as is
  Future<void> set({String key, String value}) async {
    await flutterSecureStorage.write(key: key, value: value);
  }

  Future<String> get({String key}) async {
    return flutterSecureStorage.read(key: key);
  }
}

class Response {
  int statusCode = 200;

  Response() {
    print('http post completed');
  }
}

class AuthenticationRepository {
  final secureStorage = SecureStorageService.getInstance;
  String accessToken = '';

  /// Encapsulates the slow init of a http.post call. When all ready, returns
  /// the AuthenticationRepository in a usable state
  Future<AuthenticationRepository> initStorage() async {
    try {
      // Mock http response
      final response = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => Response());

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        accessToken = 'access_token from http value';
        await secureStorage.set(
            key: 'access_token',
            value: accessToken);
        print('access token set');
        // snipped other calls for brevity
      }
    } catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print('Exception occurred: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace');
    }
    return this;
  }
}

class SingleStoragePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SingleStoragePageState createState() => _SingleStoragePageState();
}

class _SingleStoragePageState extends State<SingleStoragePage> {
  Future<AuthenticationRepository> authRepo;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    authRepo = AuthenticationRepository().initStorage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Singleton Storage'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<AuthenticationRepository>(
          future: authRepo,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print('FutureBuilder re/building');
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text('Access token: ${snapshot.data.accessToken}');
            }
            return Text('loading...');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. But I am already instantiating the Singleton in my main file. I should not have to declare it in this package correct?

Comment: That's not how a singleton works.  Singleton just guarantees you have only one instance.  It doesn't make non-static methods, static (i.e. accessible without an instance, runnable from the class definition itself).  So if you try to instantiate `SecureStorageService` when an instance already exists, you'll get the already-created instance back.

Comment: I understand that, however I am unable to instantiate the Singleton. It complains that the method is not found. I guess my real question is how can I instantiate the Singleton correctly in this file?

Comment: I've added a code sample that hopefully illustrates a typical setup of singleton & its instantiation for Dart.

Comment: Thank you so much. You were perfectly correct about the instance thing tripping me up. I assumed based on the examples I had seen online that SFF had an instance method that could be called.