# Pass a parameter to the main function in flutter

Tags: flutter, function, parameters, pass-by-reference

Can I pass a parameter to the main function in flutter? I yes then how?

```
void main(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that,

because when you start an app on your device there are also no parameters that are passed.

you can check this
[Question in stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004302/how-do-you-pass-arguments-from-command-line-to-main-in-flutter-dart)